# Align equations with text before one of them

Tags: math-mode, align

I want to align 2 similar equations such that the first is directly over the other.

```
$ a + b = c $ \\
text $ d + e = f $ \\
```

How do I do that?

It should look like:

```
     $ a + b = c $ \\
text $ d + e = f $ \\
```

My original code:

```
Die Wronskimatrix entspricht dann die linear Kombination der Funktionen: \\
$ {\color{orange} \alpha x + \beta x^2 = 0}$ \\
und $ {\color{orange} \alpha 1 + \beta 2x = 0   }$ für die Ableitungen\\
```

I want it to look like:

```
Die Wronskimatrix entspricht dann die linear Kombination der Funktionen: \\
    $ {\color{orange} \alpha x + \beta x^2 = 0}$ \\
und $ {\color{orange} \alpha 1 + \beta 2x = 0   }$ für die Ableitungen\\
```

I tried using `\begin{alinged}[b]` as shown below but it didn't compile with error of missing `}` in a wierd place.

Comment: Can you provide some broader context of the information surrounding your code snippet? Specifically, this information seems to be presented in regular text/paragraph mode with line-breaks via ``\\``. Instead, it is far better to use a *display* like `\begin{align*}`...`\end{align*}`.

Comment: Where should I place \begin{align*}...\end{align*} to avoid collisions with my code?

Comment: With the context of your code, `align*` is not a viable option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


zzzzzzzzzzzz

text $\begin{aligned}[b]
   a + b &= c  \\
  d + e &= f 
\end{aligned}$

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you showed a line of text above and another below, just to show that it works in context.  (Of course, just cheating and using `\phantom{text }$...` would avoid all possible baseline problems.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton ^^

Comment: The gap between the two lines with the math expressions is larger than the gap between a math line and the adjacent text line.  (Not surprising, actually, since the `aligned` and `align` vertical separation is more than the default baselineskip.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, quite probably you would set the whole thing off in a display construct such as `center` so the `\lineskip` difference wouldn't be obtrusive, or you could correct fro it of course.

Comment: Got it, I should have placed the color enviroment to encapsulate the aligned. Tnx!

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
text \alignLongstack{a + b =& c\\ d + e =& f} more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

The default baselineskip for a long stack can be set in the preamble with `\setstackgap{L}{<length>}`.

If it is to be literally used within typeset text, one may wish to add `\strutlongstacks{T}` to get proper line spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
text \alignLongstack{a + b =& c\\ d + e =& f}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Display your formulas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\section{A}

Die Wronskimatrix entspricht dann die linear Kombination der Funktionen:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&&& \color{orange} \alpha x + \beta x^2 = 0 \\
\text{und}&\qquad&& \color{orange} \alpha 1 + \beta 2x = 0
\end{alignat*}
für die Ableitungen.

\section{B}

Die Wronskimatrix entspricht dann die linear Kombination der Funktionen:
\begin{align*}
& \color{orange} \alpha x + \beta x^2 = 0 \\
\shortintertext{und}
& \color{orange} \alpha 1 + \beta 2x = 0
\end{align*}
für die Ableitungen.

\end{document}
```

[image]